# nan in covariance matrix

Tags: matlab, nan, covariance

I have the following covariance matrix

```
    a       b       c       d
a   0.0161  0.0009  0.0008  0.0000001
b   0.0009  0.0163     NaN     0.0006
c   0.0008     NaN   0.0209       NaN
d   0       0.0006     NaN     0.0077
```

I would like to filter this matrix so that only those columns and rows that are non NaN remain, is there a way to do this without having nested loops?

so this should become

```
    a       b          d
 a  0.0161  0.0009  0.0000001
 b  0.0009  0.0163  0.0006
 d  0       0.0006  0.0077
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To pull out rows in matrix A without NaN you can do this:

A = A(~sum(isnan(A),2),:);

To pull out columns in matrix A without NaN you can do this:

A = A(:,~sum(isnan(A),1));

Unfortunately, you can't mix and match them like you are trying to do in your example where sometimes you are removing rows with NaN while keeping columns values with NaN and sometimes you are removing columns with NaN and keeping row values.